# Xamarin Android Class Library project template

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I recently updated Visual Studio 2019 to 16.9.1 and when I'm trying to add a new Xamarin Android Class Library, I can't find it under the templates. All I get is this:

[image: possible missing project templates]

There used to be a project template for "Android Class Library" and it no longer seems to be in the list. Am I missing something? Is this expected? I've tried using "Class library" (the one highlighted in the attached image) but it's missing a reference to "Mono.Android" and I'm unable to add it. Has the "Android Class Library" intentionally been removed or have I ruined my Visual Studio configuration somehow?

I believe I'm using the correct "workload" in Visual Studio Installer:
[image: workload in VS Installer]

Comment: VS team has addressed the problem and the fix is pending release. Please check: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-find-Xamarin-Android-Binding-Libr/1363176?space=8&q=android+binding